# ArgumentException (parameter is not valid) error when instantiating Bitmap object

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pathtoimage);

Pathtoimage is the full, absolute path to a jpg. I get an ArgumentException (parameter is not valid) error. What am I doing wrong?

CODE:

```
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageFilename); 

        var sobelEdgeDetector = new SobelEdgeDetector();

        sobelEdgeDetector.Apply(bitmap);
```

Called with:

```
var sobelEdgeDetector = new Sobel();

        sobelEdgeDetector.OutlineEdges(@"E:\Users\Me\Pictures\Error.jpg");
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it throws an ArgumentException, MSDN says that only FileNotFoundException could be thrown... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx Which .NET FX version are you running on?

Comment: Can you show what you have for `pathtoimage` ? I don't even see ArgumentException listed for this constructor; there's just FileNotFoundException.

Comment: What is the value of `pathtoimage`?

Comment: Exceptions are documented at Image.FromFile().  Somewhat, GDI+ exceptions are pretty weak sauce.  How big is this image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i resolved after study the library carefully..
SobelEdgeDetector() needs the Grayscale Image
So your code will be

```
 Private Image getEdge(Bitmap img)
            {
            Bitmap originalImage = img; // 
            // get grayscale image
            originalImage = Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.RMY.Apply(img);
            // apply edge filter   
            IFilter ff = new SobelEdgeDetector();                     
            Bitmap b = ff.Apply(originalImage);
            originalImage.Dispose();
            return (Image)b;
            }
```